# How to handle lists of multiple entities being born, drawn and killed simultaneously without conflicts?

Tags: java, list, graphics, concurrentmodification

I'll try to keep it short, this is the situation:

- **Creature Class** : x y coordinates, moves around randomly and shoots **Projectiles**
- **Projectile Class** : x y coordinates, moves in a straight line and dies when impacting **Creatures**
- **Arena Class** : JPanel which iterates over the lists of creatures and projectiles and calls their draw() method.

> If you dont't wish to read any further this is my main question: What
>   is the best way to  handle Projectiles being created and inserted in
>   the projectile list of the JPanel? Is having such a list is even a
>   good idea in the first place?

Should I create a mutex semaphore which acquires a permit whenever the JPanel is iterating over the projectile list and releases the permit once it's done? I'm running into trouble when the creatures decide to insert a new bullet while iterating over the list. If this is the case, what is the best way of letting the creature class access this semaphore?

Also I would like to add that I usually use this tactic to avoid concurrent modifications in similar situations:

1. List of items ready to be added
2. List of "active" items
3. List of items ready to be removed

And then:

```
if (!toBeAdded.isEmpty()) {
    activeItems.addAll(toBeAdded);
    activetoBeAdded.clear();
}

if(!toBeRemoved.isEmpty()) {
    activeItems.removeAll(toBeRemoved);
    toBeRemoved.clear();
} 

for (Item i : activeItems) {
// do something
}
```

But this of course doesn't work in this particular situation because I am just "moving" the problem from the active list to the toBeAdded one, I still get a concurrent modification if my creatures try and add bullets to the toBeAdded list while it's being used.

Comment: As a general suggestion, the obvious issue is to guard against race conditions, if you're using the Swing paint system, you can't control the paint process (I might occur at any time), if you're using some kind of thread to add and remove the entities, you could synchronise the access to the list or use a [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://www.java67.com/2012/09/what-is-copyonwritearraylist-in-java-example-vs-arraylist.html?m=1)

Comment: Without more context, you should have a "main" loop which is responsible for managing the life cycle if your entities and scheduling paint updates, so, it'd only be the main thread and your paint method accessing it, if you're using the CopyOnWriteArrayList, you can use its Iterator to paint the entities, as the iterator is a separate copy 

Comment: @MadProgrammer Hi thanks for the advice I will be checking out the CopyOnWriteArrayList, as for the repainting I have an ExecutorService calling the repaint method of the JPanel every 16 milliseconds, I suppose I could start working from there to avoid any conflicts.

Comment: The updating of the entities should occur together as part of the update portion of the main loop, this makes it easier to manage